# Help in this proposition of Hartshorne's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to understand this proposition in Hartshorne's book:

[image]
The theorem 1.8A says

[image]

I put $B=K[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$, am I right? If so, why $K[X_1\ldots,X_n]/(f)=Z(f)$?

Thanks

Comment: The equality you are asking about does not make sense: on the left of the equal sign you have a ring and on the right you have a subset of affine space, and the two cannot be equal!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez yes you're right, but what is the candidate to be $B$?

Comment: $B=K[X_1,...,X_n], \mathfrak p=(f),K[X_1,...,X_n]/(f)=A(Z(f)) $

Comment: Thank you @GeorgesElencwajg for helping me again.

Comment: You are welcome, user42912.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg In this question, does variety means affine variety? Otherwise, does "a variety corresponds to a prime ideal" make sense?

Comment: @Babai Yes, in this context variety means affine subvariety of $\mathbb A^n$. And, yes, these varieties correspond exactly to prime ideals.